# Непонятный параметр при подключении таблицы стилей

Tags: css

На многих сайтах при подключении таблицы в конце адреса, после **?** передаются непонятные цифры-параметры

```
<link href="http://www.htmlbook.ru/ie/rus/x3.css?1234">
```

Для чего нужны эти цифры 1234? Что они вообще могут? 
Если вопрос-баян, извиняюсь, поиск результатов не дал

Answer (score 6):

Вариантов несколько:

1. Самый банальный - передаём какой-то параметр что бы "сбросить кеш" для этого файла. Параметр изменился/появился - значит нужно перезапросить файл. Судя по наглядности параметра: 1234 - это этот случай и есть.
2. css генерится динамически в зависимости от параметра.

Comment: 2 пункт поясни пожалуйста

Comment: грубо говоря:

    if ($_REQUEST['param1'] == 12345) {
        echo 'background-color: black;';
    } else {
        echo 'background-color: white;';
    }